# Spring Transactional with Isolation.SERIALIZABLE does not lock database row for updates

Tags: hibernate, jpa, transactions, isolation-level

I have a Spring Boot application with an H2 database and I have implemented a service with the annotation to use a Transaction with isolation level SERIALIZABLE.
The plan is to lock the dataset in the database, so that a concurrent process cannot update the database while my service is still holding the data for update.

```
@Transactional(isolation = Isolation.SERIALIZABLE) public class MyService {

  public OrderResource addContract(final Long orderId, final ContractResource contractResource) {

    // fetch the contract with Spring Data JPA repository
    final Contract contract = contractRepository.findById(contractId);

    // to test the scenario manually I wait for 10 seconds. In this timespan I manually change the row in the database
    try {
      Thread.sleep(10000);
    } catch (final InterruptedException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

    updateService.addContract(contract, contractResource);

  }
}
```

I would now have expected the affected record to be locked in the DB (for example by a Hibernate generated statement like 'SELECT FOR UPDATE'), but this is not the case.

Do I have to pay attention to anything else in addition to the "Isolation.SERIALIZABLE" to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Serializable` isolation level does not necessarily mean exclusive database lock. For example, PostgreSQL implements the [Serializable Snapshot Isolation pattern](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/transaction-iso.html#:%7E:text=database%20literature%20as-,Serializable%20Snapshot%20Isolation,-%2C%20which%20builds%20on). The database will check possible serializable anomalies before committing. The behaviour is similar to the [optimistic locking approach](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-optimistic-locking).

If you want to select rows with exclusive lock, you should probably apply `SELECT FOR UPDATE` directly. If you want to stick with JPA, then you can try using [`Lock` query annotation](https://www.baeldung.com/java-jpa-transaction-locks#:%7E:text=When%20using%20Pessimistic%20Locking%2C%20the,specify%20the%20lock%20timeout%20value.).